# Is end to end encryption (e2ee) possible with agora video chat?

Tags: reactjs, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

My employer uses agora.io for video chat functionality.  We've been asked to look at how we add end to end encryption between our react website and mobile apps (flutter iOS & Android).  I'm solely looking at the web side currently.

Reading the doc and searching google it seems to me it is not possible, unless I am missing something?

It was suggested that Electron might offer a solution, but surely that will run into the same issue?  Unless they idea is to provide custom e2ee solution.

Sorry for vague question, but a little stumped right now.

Comment: Agora offers only media encryption out of the box: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/channel_encryption_web?platform=Web

I dont think that you can implement e2ee into agora - or Im just low skilled :)

Comment: Thanks @veter. Even asking them directly they avoided directly answering the question and just confirmed they offered 'encryption' and provided the same link you did. I guess that's my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi E2EE is a generic term for encrypting communication between endpoints. If you're looking for packet encryption, so that your data is encrypted while it's transferred to the nearest edge in the Agora network - you can use [media stream encryption](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/channel_encryption_web_ng?platform=Web) on Web and Flutter. There's a diagram on the linked website that goes into more detail.

Comment: It's the media stream encryption that I'm confused about - I'm tasked with ensuring the video calls are encrypted FROM agora, as they are chinese owned and they seem to have removed previous references to supporting e2ee.

Comment: If you're using media stream encryption, your video data would be encrypted during transit across the Agora SD-RTN. You can also use geo-fencing to guarantee your data never goes to a data center in China if that's a concern. https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/region_web_ng_rtc?platform=Web